# Baking Cookies: Comparing a decreasing variable and a constant

Tags: ruby, timer

Hi I'm new to programming and Ruby.

In this script, I am a baker and I want to make cookies. The baker i.e. the user will give a baking time as input, and the program needs to compare that input time with the constant recipe time.

When the recipe time = baking time, the baker will be notified that they're ready. For example, cooking_time given by user is 10, and the Recipe_time is 8. As we bake the cookie, cooking_time -= 1, and once it hits 2 i.e. reached recipe_time, the cookies will be ready and user prompted to take them out or not? If not, cooking_time will continue to decrease which will result in the cookies being burnt.

What is the best to go about doing this comparison?

Below is what i've got so far, im currently stuck the the 'ready?' method. Thanks guys!

```
class Cookies

  attr_reader :doughy,:almost_ready,:ready,:burned
  attr_accessor :baking_time

  def initialize
    @perfection = false
  end

  def ready?
    while @perfection != true
            #This is where I got Stuck
    end
  end

  def perfection?
    @perfection = true if @baking_time = @recipe_time
  end

  def move_out
    answer = ""
    puts "It took #{@elapsed_time} minutes but our #{@name} are ready! Do you want to take them out? Answer Y/N"
    answer = gets.chomp
    if answer == "Y"
      puts "Great! Leave them to cool for 2 minutes then we can eat 'em!"         
    else
      puts 'burnt'
    end 
  end

  def bake
    @start_time = Time.now
    @baking_time -= 1
    ready?
  end

end

class ChocChip < Cookies

  attr_reader :recipe_time, :name

  def initialize(baking_time)
    @name = "Chocolate Chip Cookies"
    @baking_time = baking_time
    @recipe_time = 8
  end

end

class Muesli < Cookies

  attr_reader :recipe_time, :name

  def initialize(baking_time)
    @name = "Muesli Cookies"
    @baking_time = baking_time
    @recipe_time = 10
  end

end

puts "WELCOME TO I <3 COOKIES BAKERY\n\n"
puts "What kind of cookie would you like to bake?\n\n"
puts "Enter 1 for CC or 2 for Muesli"
cookie_choice = gets.chomp
puts "How long would you want to bake them for?"
cookie_baking_time = gets.chomp.to_i
if cookie_choice == "1"
  my_choc_chips = ChocChip.new(cookie_baking_time)
  my_choc_chips.bake
elsif cookie_choice == "2"
  my_muesli = Muesli.new(cookie_baking_time)
  my_muesli.bake
else
  puts "Err..please choose a type of cookie you want to bake!"
end
```

Comment: that seems a bit harsh...if it's so awful why not just downvote?

Comment: @chumakoff  Your comment is not civilized - please edit it or take it off

Comment: @chumakoff sorry, I've just started Ruby, nope, programming just 2 weeks ago. If this is not a place for beginners to ask questions do redirect me to somewhere more appropriate? Thank you.

Comment: chumekoff, now that @mudasobwa has identified your problem, consider posting your working code at SO's sister-site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). There you will get useful advice on how you can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

It´s baking that takes time, not checking readiness :)

```
def ready?
  @baking_time == @recipe_time
end

def bake
  @baking_time = 0
  while !ready? do
    @baking_time += 1
    sleep 1  # sleep for one second
  end
end
```

The above will stop execution for `@recipe_time`. Whether you just wanted to fake baking, comment `sleep` out.